# GCP Load balancer with cross project Cloud Run services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

currently we are using GCP global Loadbalancer with serverless backend with Cloud Run services.
All services are deployed in one project per env dev/test/prod and split into multiple regions with loadbalancer in prod project.

Issue is that we'd like to have separate project for each set of services that each team have own space for services. This will allow us to better manage IAM and handle issues in error reporting.

Is it possible to have one project for load balancer and X projects for teams with cloud run connected to this loadbalancer?

Comment: I succeeded tonight. I will write an article on this, very interesting! Can you wait a week or so? Can I name you? (if so and if you have a medium user, share it with me)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, did u every publish something? Would be nice to find out if there is a way to do it.

Comment: @Jesse, yes of course, I forgot to put the link. Here it is: https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-load-balancing-go-beyond-your-own-project-adfa1c8b001d

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation:

[Serverless network endpoint groups overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts#limitations)

> "Load balancers using serverless NEG backends **must be created in the
> same project** as the Cloud Run (fully managed), App Engine, or Cloud
> Functions services pointed to by the NEG"

Therefore I do not believe it is possible to have the load balancer in one project and the serverless NEG backends in another project.

Comment: I found that there is feature request regarding cross project serverless NEGs
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167570531